# How to make local application accessible for other pc in my local network

Tags: windows, networking, port, localhost, hosting

I would like to host an application from a local Windows pc, for my local network

I have an ASP.NET Core application (running in debug mode) on Windows pc A (192.168.1.10) on port 5001

There is another Windows pc B (192.168.1.11) that would like to access the application that pc A is hosting

When i disable the firewall on pc A, I am able to ping pc A from pc B, but I am unable to browse the web application hosted on port 5001 (https://192.168.18.10:5001)

There is no active CORS policy on the hosted application

Are there any steps that i've overlooked?
Do you have any thoughts on how I could resolve this issue?

UPDATE: I have now installed NGINX as a reverse proxy and this seems to work.
Is there any information on why I could not achieve this without NGINX?

Comment: "an application": more detail might be useful.

Comment: I have an asp . net core MVC application,its a web application

Comment: What error do you get when browsing to this URL?

Comment: Hello Harrymc, i get the message "Connection refused", which makes me think it has something to do with the firewall?

Comment: @harrymc, i have updated my question with NGINX

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, i have updated my question with NGINX

Comment: How have you hosted a web application before without a web server?

Comment: @harrymc not in my LAN, I have tried to open the ports but without success, only with the reverse proxy I was able to handle the requests ,any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL must be sent to a web-server to be handled, which is
why it worked for you after you added NGINX.

It's possible for an application to open a socket on a port
and listen for incoming data, but then you need to create
a protocol to be used between your server and client apps,
and cannot use the helpful functionality of the web-server.